# Why am I getting repeated error message when I closed parenthesis

Tags: google-bigquery

Why am i getting an error on a closed paranthesis when it seems that my code is correct:

WITH
longest_used_bike AS (
SELECT
bike_id,
SUM (duration_minutes) AS trip_duration
FROM bigquery-public-data.austin_bikeshare.bikeshare_trips
GROUP BY bike_id
ORDER BY trip_duration DESC
)     Syntax error: Expected "(" or "," or keyword SELECT but got end of script at [9:4]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You just need to add `` around the table name:- `bigquery-public-data.austin_bikeshare.bikeshare_trips`
2. You get this error because a CTE (i.e. the `WITH` statement) is only part of a query.It needs to be followed by another statement. Usually `SELECT` works. So you need to add one more statement at end.

Just change it as following and that should work:-

```
WITH longest_used_bike AS (
  SELECT
    bikeid,
    SUM(duration_minutes) AS trip_duration
  FROM `bigquery-public-data.austin_bikeshare.bikeshare_trips`
  GROUP BY bikeid
  ORDER BY trip_duration DESC
)
/* add your SELECT statement here */
SELECT *
FROM longest_used_bike;
```

Comment: I did so and unfortunately I still get the same error message!!!

Comment: Have updated my answer.Please check again